# Error while deploying setup web project of vs 2003

Tags: asp.net

I am getting error as

```
           The specified psth is unavailable.The Internet Information Server might not be running or the path exists and is redirected to another machine. Please check the status of this virtual directory in the Internet Services Manager
```

Answer (score 0):

there isn't much information to go on in that message however I think it's one of two possibilities:

1. Your path as wrong (can you provide it?)
2. The folder in IIS isn't set (can you check this?)

All of which is from the error message so I'm not being very helpful, but from experience I think it's most likely to be the path so I would double check and then check again where your deploying to.

Cheers